# Selenium Web Driver Phantom JS c# Continuar de onde parou

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

Estou desenvolvendo um robô no *Selenium*. Porém, esse robô tem hora que interage com o usuário. Porém, eu não consigo fazer ele continuar de onde parou.

Vou dar um exemplo:

> Faz de conta que esse robô faz uma consulta de seu CPF num site para ver o quanto de saldo vc tem disponível para compra, ai ele consulta e retorna seu saldo e pergunta se vc quer continuar e se vc aceitar, vc coloca seus dados, então o robô tem que continuar e avançar p próxima tela e preencher esses dados (tudo ocultamente usando o `phantomJs`).

Isso é possível?

Answer (score 0):

Sim, só colocar o evento de iniciar o PhantomJS no `Click` e fazer uma nova chamada.

Ex:

1. Faz o que tem que fazer com o PhantomJS e finaliza ele.
2. Chama a tela para o Usuário fazer a sua operação.
3. Chama novamente o PhantomJS e continue.

Apenas uma Ideia.